# TortoiseHG Workbench's Tool Resolve adding diff text to file

Tags: merge, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a strange issue that I can't seem to pin down. Whenever I use Tool Resolve, the first time I click 'Tool Resolve', diffs are added to the file. Here's what ended up being in a file after a merge conflict fix:

Tool resolve:

```
function dataValid(data) {
  return "requests" in data && "suggestion" in data;
<<<<<<< dest
}
=======
}>>>>>>> source
```

Original:

```
function dataValid(data) {
  return "requests" in data && "suggestion" in data;
}

function shiftTypeToTitle(shiftType) {
  // Removed logic
}
```

My commit was to remove `shiftTypeToTitle`.

If Tool Resolve is not able to automatically resolve the conflict, the 3-way diff window opens. I can see the diff text in there. If I close out of that window without saving and click "Tool Resolve" again, the diff text is gone this time!

If Tool Resolve is able to automatically resolve the conflict, I have no opportunity to cancel without saving and retry like I can above, so in that case, the diff text is always committed to the file.

This is driving me absolutely insane; does anyone have any suggestions of have I can go about finding out why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: *Plain commit* can't produce merge-conflict. You have to describe your case deeper, step-by-step

Comment: This was my use case, I haven't left anything out other than removing the logic in the function. This happens with _all of my merges_.

Comment: There was a version of TortoiseHg that had a bug that looked like this.  I don't recall the version, but just update to the latest.